# How can I open with blank page on this rss javascript nor html?

Tags: javascript, html, rss

I have a website which includes this RSS JavaScript. When I click feed, it opens same page, but I don't want to do that. How can I open with blank page? I have my current HTML and JavaScript below.

**HTML CODE**

```
<tr>
    <td style="background-color: #808285" class="style23" >

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#ticker1').rssfeed('http://www.demircelik.com.tr/map.asp').ajaxStop(function () {
                    $('#ticker1 div.rssBody').vTicker({ showItems: 3 });
                });
            });
        </script>     

        <div  id="ticker1" >                                                         
            <br />
        </div>                                                                                     
   </td>
</tr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
(function ($) {
    var current = null;
    $.fn.rssfeed = function (url, options) {
        // Set pluign defaults
        var defaults = {
            limit: 10,
            header: true,
            titletag: 'h4',
            date: true,
            content: true,
            snippet: true,
            showerror: true,
            errormsg: '',
            key: null
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // Functions
        return this.each(function (i, e) {
            var $e = $(e);
            // Add feed class to user div
            if (!$e.hasClass('rssFeed')) $e.addClass('rssFeed');
            // Check for valid url
            if (url == null) return false;
            // Create Google Feed API address
            var api = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q=" + url;
            if (options.limit != null) api += "&num=" + options.limit;
            if (options.key != null) api += "&key=" + options.key;
            // Send request
            $.getJSON(api, function (data) {
                // Check for error
                if (data.responseStatus == 200) {
                    // Process the feeds
                    _callback(e, data.responseData.feed, options);
                }
                else {
                    // Handle error if required
                    if (options.showerror) if (options.errormsg != '') {
                        var msg = options.errormsg;
                    }
                    else {
                        var msg = data.responseDetails;
                    };
                    $(e).html('<div class="rssError"><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
                };
            });
        });
    };
    // Callback function to create HTML result
    var _callback = function (e, feeds, options) {
            if (!feeds) {
                return false;
            }
            var html = '';
            var row = 'odd';
            // Add header if required
            if (options.header) html += '<div class="rssHeader">' + '<a href="' + feeds.link + '"  title="' + feeds.description + '">' + feeds.title + '</a>' + '</div>';
            // Add body
            html += '<div class="rssBody">' + '<ul>';
            // Add feeds
            for (var i = 0; i < feeds.entries.length; i++) {
                // Get individual feed
                var entry = feeds.entries[i];
                // Format published date
                var entryDate = new Date(entry.publishedDate);
                var pubDate = entryDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + entryDate.toLocaleTimeString();
                // Add feed row
                html += '<li class="rssRow ' + row + '">' + '<' + options.titletag + '><a href="' + entry.link + '" title="View this feed at ' + feeds.title + '">' + entry.title + '</a></' + options.titletag + '>'
                if (options.date) html += '<div>' + pubDate + '</div>'
                if (options.content) {
                    // Use feed snippet if available and optioned
                    if (options.snippet && entry.contentSnippet != '') {
                        var content = entry.contentSnippet;
                    }
                    else {
                        var content = entry.content;
                    }
                    html += '<p>' + content + '</p>'
                }
                html += '</li>';
                // Alternate row classes
                if (row == 'odd') {
                    row = 'even';
                }
                else {
                    row = 'odd';
                }
            }
            html += '</ul>' + '</div>'
            $(e).html(html);
        };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you want to open a new page when you click on the feed widget title or each individual feed item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change this:

```
 html += '<li class="rssRow '+row+'">' + 
                '<'+ options.titletag +'><a href="'+ entry.link +'" title="View this feed at '+ feeds.title +'">'+ entry.title +'</a></'+ options.titletag +'>'
```

to

```
html += '<li class="rssRow '+row+'">' + 
                '<'+ options.titletag +'><a href="'+ entry.link +'" title="View this feed at '+ feeds.title +'" target="_blank">'+ entry.title +'</a></'+ options.titletag +'>'
```

Comment: basically, you need to add target="_blank"